# Join lines in Eclipse without whitespace

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

For example, joining these two lines with the keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> in Eclipse results in the following:

```
something().somethingElse()
    .yetAnotherThing();

// Joining the above two lines results in this:
something().somethingElse() .yetAnotherThing();
```

Is there a way to join those lines so it results in this:

```
// Notice there is no excess whitespace
something().somethingElse().yetAnotherThing();
```

Comment: Was the space there at the end of the first line originally or did the CTRL-J add it in?

Comment: No, CTRL-J added it in.

Answer (score 5):

As far as the specific "join lines" command introduced with Eclipse 3.3 which in my case is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, I think we are currently stuck with the addition of the space. It is a [known bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=412412).

You might throw the dice and instead select the lines and try the format command (for me it is bound to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) to see if that behaves any better.

Selecting the lines ahead of requesting the format should limit the scope of formatting to the selected lines.

Comment: Join the lines, select the line and format works. Note: must select the lines to format, or it will format the whole file, which is usually not desirable. If you wrongly format the whole file, it may take very long to redo this step and Eclipse may crash!